# folding, curly bracket under the function name

Tags: folding, filetype-c++, filetype-c

I have these two functions

```
  void function_one(){
    return;
  }

  void function_two()
  {
    return;
  }
```

when I use `zM` to fold the functions I get

```
  +--  3 lines: void function_one(){--

  void function_two()
  +--  3 lines: {-
```

the `function_two` doesn't get a nice folding, How I can get the same folding as for `function_one` in `function_two`?

PD: I use two code styles, curly brackets on same line as function name and curly braces under the function name, because some projects use one code style and other projects use the other code style.

Comment: I assume this is C or C++?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yes, both c and c++

Answer (score 1):

I did define [VimFold4C](https://github.com/LucHermitte/VimFold4C) that tries its best to fold C & C++ codes. The caveat is when we are modifying the code: I'm using caches in order to speed up the fold processing, but alas it has quirks.